# Wordpress, Jquery, wp_enqueue_script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am in need of help!

Can someone PLEASE walk me through the specifics, from start to finish, on how to add a jquery plugin script to my wordpress site?

I'm new to Jquery and I have searched the web for the last week.  I've tried it myself several times and its just not working.  I've asked for help on other forums and I haven't received any answers.  Is this something fairly simple to do?

Just to let you know, I am in need step by step instructions.  It's just that when I ask questions about this on forums, people are giving me answers and assuming that I already know certain things...I am a beginner with jquery and I need help with each step of the process of adding a jquery script, from start to finish.

The script I want to add is here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/03/09/a-fresh-bottom-slide-out-menu-with-jquery/

I want to add it on my homepage in the theme I'm using.

1)  How do I call the jquery (wp_enqueue_script)
2)  Where do I place this (above)
3)  CSS - do I simply append the css from the script to my style.css file?
4)  How do I call the script to action on the wordpress page?
5)  How do I incorporate the html?

These are some of the questions that I have.  I've been searching all over the net and usually people assume that people know how to incorporate javascript libraries into their themes....well some of us beginners need help :-)

Any assistance is appreciated!

Thanks!!!

~T

Comment: (A) "Walking you thru on Skype" is not really in the spirit of stackoverflow. This is a Q&A site, where ideally other people will also benefit from an answer to your question. (B) That being said, please provide specific information on what jQuery script you want to add.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, here is some good info on [how to write a question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) also you should read the website FAQs

Comment: Not to be rude or to push you away, but maybe  you need to consider hiring a freelancer on a site like http://elance.com. One-on-one tech support is a requirement that is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Wow....that is a little rude.  I can't seem to understand why people are so reluctant to help newbies on this topic.  Where is the sense of community?  It is really discouraging.  I'm new to Stack Overflow, new to jquery, I'm trying to learn.  Can any of you help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slide-out menu you linked to consists of images, a stylesheet, a minified version of the jQuery library and and index.html containing the javascript of the menu.

The jQuery included in the archive you downloaded is not neccessary, as jQuery is by default included in wordpress. If you want to add the newest minified jQuery to WP do it from the google libraries in your *functions.php* like so:

```
function jq_load_from_google() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery',
            'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'jq_load_from_google');
```

You could append the css to your existing stylesheet or (as in the following example) add it to the theme separately. Rename the stylesheet to menu.css (or the like), place the images and stylesheet in your themes /css and /images folders and add the following to your theme's *header.php* **before** `wp_head()` and after your main stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/menu.css" type="text/css" />
```

Add the javascript (the second script that contains code, **not** the jQuery line) included in the downloaded *index.html* to your theme's *header.php* **after** `wp_head()`.

Change the all occurences `#menu` in the js to your wordpress menu's ul's ID.

Comment: I've done everything, the menus show the hover effect, but not the sliding effect.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

See the WP docs for details and examples: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Use Firebug to look for errors and conflicts: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I have looked at the codex multiple times and I don't understand it...I'm a newbie and I need a human to show me step by step.  Can you help?